# WCF service multiple behaviors

Tags: .net, wcf

I've done some WCF, but it's been a while, and I've never had to configure a service from scratch.

Apparently, while you can only have one *behavior configuration*, it's possible to attach multiple *behaviors* to a WCF service:

```
ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Services.FooService), ServiceEndpointUri);
WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();       
ServiceEndpoint sep = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Contracts.IFooService), binding, string.Empty);
sep.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
sep.Behaviors.Add(new MyCustomEndpointBehavior());
```

I'm wondering:

1. Is it possible to attach multiple service behaviors to a service? ... or, for that matter, multiple endpoint behaviors?  Or are you limited to at most one of each?  That's not clear to me from this snippet (which is the closest thing to an answer I've turned up so far in my search).
2. Is it possible to do this via configuration (rather than programmatically)?

Answer (score 2):

You just create a named behavior then list your behaviors as sub-items of your named behavior.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyExampleBehavior">
          <webHttp />
          <MyCustomEndpointBehavior />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Example.Endpoints.MyEndpoint">
         <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="MyExampleBehavior" .../>
    </service>
  </services>
```

using `SvcConfigEditor.exe` (which should have been included with your visual studio install under the name "Service Configuration Editor") it can help you edit and configure .config files and create complex bindings the one above easily.

[image]

Comment: and in the `<service>` element I would set `behaviorConfiguration` to the named behavior (`MyExampleBehavior`)?

Comment: Yes (I think)... I would just use the editor, you can set the configuration in there via the GUI